# Create Zip in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, zip

I am actually wondering why when I create a zip file, and I download it just after, I can't open it because it's broken ..

This is the code I am actually using .

```
        string url = ((LinkButton)sender).Tag;
        var downloadFileName = string.Format(((LinkButton)sender).ID + ".zip");
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//Wireframes//" + url);

        using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            zip.AddEntry("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//Wireframes//" + url, zip.Name);
            zip.AddDirectory("C://inetpub//wwwroot//Files//Wireframes//" + url);
            zip.Save(downloadFileName);
        }


        Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + downloadFileName);
```

Also, I am adding directly all the directories with their files inside.

Comment: fyi your string format does nothing.

Comment: What's up with the mixed slashes in your uri's? ('//' and '\\')?

Comment: My string format is creating nameofthefile.zip

Comment: But you don't actually need `string.Format` to do it. You should be using `Path.Combine`.

Comment: Have you tried opening the zip file directly on the server?

Comment: It will do the same right ? Because it's just the same of the file that im creating

Comment: Yeah I try to open it after download, and I can't, the file is broken

Comment: Are you actually sending the file data as a response? I only see a header there

Comment: Oh yeah, I am not sending the bytes ? right ?

Comment: Not in this snippet you're not.

Comment: Indeed, I think it's something like Response.TransmitFile

Comment: So i just have to add the buffersize in the header like this ?

Comment: size = zip.BufferSize;
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", size.ToString());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not sending the actual data.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + downloadFileName);
Response.TransmitFile(downloadFileName);
Response.End();
```

Comment: It says that It can't find the file, as if the zip.save is not working . But it's the good path though.

Comment: You might want to pass the full path to the file in the call to TransmitFile()

Comment: Thanks . It's downloading in the download folder though. Can I add a header to choose where you want to save the file you download ?

Comment: From server side, you can't tell where to put the downloaded file on the client computer.

Comment: Can't they juste select where they want to put it with this kind of dialog box  ?

Comment: I don't know, but that is an other question you're asking here. It would be nice if you marked my answer as a solution to your original question.